# When to use memory and when not to use?

Tags: memory, memory-pointer, function

I watched this [video](https://youtu.be/vYwYe-Gv_XI?t=258) and he uses `memory` a lot like `function verify(address _signer, string memory _message, bytes memory _sig`. Why so? Could the function work without using `memory`?

While the usual `function transferFrom(address owner, address buyer, uint256 numTokens)` has no memory.

When do we use memory and when we don't have to use them?

Comment: you must either use calldata or memory by "string" and "arrays" i think. here is a more detailed answer about when to use calldata and when to use memory handle_bidder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment it depends on the type of your variable.

Many types are exactly 1 word (32 bytes) wide. These are called [Value Types](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/types.html?highlight=slice#value-types). As they have a constant width these normally exist on the stack.

Some other types (such as `array` based types like `bytes` or `string`) might take more storage and therefore are not kept on stack. The stack only keeps a reference to the data. They are called [Reference Types](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/types.html?highlight=slice#reference-types). To know where the reference is pointing it is necessary to define the storage location, which might be `calldata`, `memory` and `storage`. Depending on the location the compiler will access the data differently. This is described in detail in the [Data location](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/types.html?highlight=slice#data-location) section.