# Passing object vs address in solidity functions?

Tags: solidity

I'm trying to understand if there is any difference between passing an object vs passing the address and casting. For example:

```
function getTotalSupply(IERC20 token) view returns (uint256) {
   return token.totalSupply()
}
```

vs

```
function getTotalSupply(address token) view returns (uint256) {
   return IERC20(token).totalSupply()
}
```

I have couple questions:

- Is one of them cheaper? If so, what is the way to go about empirically determining the difference?
- In the first case, does it make a difference if I add memory (IERC20 memory token) in the function call?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As outline in quite some other post Interfaces are only syntactic sugar around addresses (e.g. [How is an interface initialised?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/118208/how-is-an-interface-initialised/118212)).

As an interface is under the hood "just" and address you cannot use `memory` on it as this will only work on reference types (see [When to use memory and when not to use?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/118503/when-to-use-memory-and-when-not-to-use/118524#118524))